# Android: OnAttach(Avitivty) calls which Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialog

I ran into a strange problem.

I started off with my MainActivity in Android project, then started another activity using the startActivity(intent). I also created a DialogFragment from my second Activity. However, it won't let me create this dialog because the Activity onAttach calls is the MainActivity which has not implemented the proper interface. I am confused why onAttach did not get the second activity in which it was initially created.

For example:

```
MainActivity extends Activity() {
intent(this, newActivity)
startActivity(intent)
}

newActivity extends Activity implements interfaces{
dFragment d = new dFragment;
}

dFragment extends DialogFragment{
interface asdf{}

onAttach(activity)
}
```

the activity in onAttach is actually the MainActivity not the newActivity. why is that?

Anyway to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Please be clear with your code.

Answer (score 0):

NVM. It was stupid a mistake. I accidentally called it from the first activity